# Local storage and model evolution

Tags: html, local-storage

I have a website where I use local storage to store user's options. Now I'm thinking of changes that will disrupt the production version.

Hence I'd like to be prepared for this situation in future versions of this site. I thought of using a version item and for ever disruptive version of the website I would be able to patch things up.

Any thoughts?